# how to apply filter on datatable in c# ? Its give Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void btn_abnrmalsixnine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {

            DataTable dt_temp = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["GridViewData"];
            //DataTable DT_Main = (DataTable)ViewState["GridViewData"];
            DataTable DT_Main = ds.Tables[0];
            dt_temp = DT_Main.Clone();
            //Button btnEdit = (Button)sender;
            //ASPxGridView Grow = (ASPxGridView)btnEdit.NamingContainer; 
            // Session["AttendanceDate"] = Grow.RowIn
            for (int i = 0; i < grv_NormalabnormalSummaryReport.VisibleRowCount; i++)
            {
                Session["AttendanceDate"] = (this.grv_NormalabnormalSummaryReport.GetRowValues(i, "AttendanceDate").ToString());
                string AttendanceDate = Session["AttendanceDate"].ToString();
                //  ASPxGridView row = (ASPxGridView)grv_NormalabnormalSummaryReport.GetSelectedFieldValues();
                dt_temp = DT_Main.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("AttendanceDate").ToString() == AttendanceDate
                                                     && r.Field<string>("AttendanceStatus").ToString() == "Abnormal" &&
                                                        r.Field<int>("TravelTime") >= 6 &&
                                                        r.Field<int>("TravelTime") <= 9).CopyToDataTable();

                grv_EmployeeList.DataSource = dt_temp;
                grv_EmployeeList.DataBind();
                popupEmployeeList.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
        }
```

Its give Exception 'The source contains no DataRow'

Comment: At which line you are getting this exception. Put all the information which you have in your question. Also comparing datetime with string show be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `CopyToDataTable()` after `Where`. Just store is in `query` and then add condition for `query.Count() > 0` which will return `true` if it has any record and then only use `CopyToDataTable()`.

Try complete code as below.

```
var query = DT_Main.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("AttendanceDate").ToString() == AttendanceDate && 
                                            r.Field<string>("AttendanceStatus").ToString() == "Abnormal" &&
                                            r.Field<int>("TravelTime") >= 6 &&
                                            r.Field<int>("TravelTime") <= 9);
if (query.Count() > 0)
{
    dt_temp = query.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: .Any() is not found in my Program

Comment: Try with `query.Count() > 0` instead of `query.Any()`.